# Show only first four lines of paragraph followed by ellipsis

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using HTML paragraph. I only want to display at most four lines of the paragraph, but the text is too long. So instead of the entire text, I want to only display the first four lines that will fit, followed by an ellipsis.

In the CSS I tried to use `word-wrap:break-word;` but it only wraps the text after the four lines.

For example, I'd like to see this (number of lines will vary by browser, but imagine for argument's sake that there's only 4):

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ac justo sodales, cursus turpis eget, lacinia risus. Aenean pretium eleifend mollis. Cras dictum ipsum eu dolor ultricies, at dictum diam auctor. In et nulla libero. Integer volutpat ornare justo ut fermentum. Ut non blandit leo, nec convallis diam. Nam congue neque vel turpis mattis scelerisque. Mauris rhoncus quam ac leo pellentesque...

When In fact the entire text would be much longer.

Comment: have a look at this walk through for multi-line `text-overflow:ellipsis` http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/

Comment: @Gokul Nath : I dont understand why this question is on hold  ? is it due to As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking ? then what about the answers below how they understood this ? and I dont know how to simplify this question more than this .

Comment: @V-Xtreme: It is a bit difficult to understand, but not everyone is a fluent English speaker here, so we cannot hold that against you :-). It looks like you have a very long paragraph, but you want it to only display the first four lines, and then an ellipsis "..." afterwards. Is this correct? Please update your question.

Comment: I have updated the question :) . Hope now it is more clear. I was added my previous comment because some people are closing the question without any comments . So the asker never knows why his question has been closed and specially though when you get some answer for the same question .

Answer (score 3):

On the same element use:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: OP requires this to work on multiple lines, which `text-overflow` does not support. Have a look at this solution by Roman Rudenko http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this can be done using css. But you can do it using javascript. Something like this

I assume that your paragraph id is 'para'.

```
<script>
var para=document.getElementById('para').innerHTML;
var p=para.substr(0,200)+"..."; // chane the 200 to your need
alert(p);

</script>
```